# How to write a function to determine the population count of a 16-bit integer using php or javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

How to write a function to determine the population count of a 16-bit
integer using php or javascript. Population count is defined as the number of bits that are
"turned on," or in others, it is the number of 1s in a binary
representation of a number. For example, the binary number 0b0000 has
a population count of 0 because there aren't any 1 bits.  0b0101 has a
population count of 2, because 2 bits turned on; 0b1110 has a
population count of 3. 0b1111111111111111 has a population count if 16
because there are sixteen 1 bits. Your function should accept an INTEGER
argument and return an INTEGER containing its population count. Example:

f(0) = 0

f(1) = 1

f(2) = 1

f(3) = 2

f(4) = 1

f(5) = 2

Comment: @EboMike - `Your function should accept an INTEGER argument and return an INTEGER containing its population count.` Not so much sounds like as almost definitely is homework. Pretty sad that devzone wouldn't even at least try this before asking the question. What has intellectualism come to these days? Get off my lawn before I turn on the sprinklers.

Comment: @treeface: Yeah, I wish people wouldn't contribute answers to those kind of questions until the person at least shows some effort on their part. Those young whippersnappers!

Answer (score 6):

Using bitwise and and right shift

```
function count(n){
  c =0;
  while(n){
    c += n&1;
    n = n>>1;
  }
  return c;
}
```

Comment: Assuming this is JavaScript, I'd actually vote the other way.  Bitwise operators can actually be *slower* in JavaScript because numbers are (IIRC) natively 64-bit floating-point; performing bitwise operations requires a conversion to 32-bit integer and then back.  Moreover, this function is leaking the c variable to the global scope without the `var` keyword.

Comment: in addition - when I run this code - i get an off by one... 8 bits in, 7 counted bits out

Answer (score 4):

The badass way?

```
    var x=0xfffe;
    x -= ((x >> 1) & 0x55555555);
    x = (((x >> 2) & 0x33333333) + (x & 0x33333333));
    x = (((x >> 4) + x) & 0x0f0f0f0f);
    x += (x >> 8);
    x += (x >> 16);
    alert(x & 0x0000003f); //15
```

Comment: This is described in the book "Hacker's delight". Available together with other algorithms here: http://www.hackersdelight.org/HDcode/newCode/pop_arrayHS.c.txt

Comment: Wow. I was thoroughly impressed.

Comment: I lifted it from here: http://aggregate.org/MAGIC/ my bible for this kind of stuff.

Comment: You should use `>>>` (unsigned shift) to avoid issues with 32-bit integers.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily *badass*, but it works...

```
<?php
$number = 3;

echo "Number: " . $number . "\n";

$bin_number = decbin($number);
$population_count = 0;

echo "Binary String Conversion: " . $bin_number . "\n";

for ($i = strlen($bin_number) - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
  $population_count += $bin_number[$i];
}

echo "Population Count: " . $population_count . "\n";
?>
```

Comment: +1 for the worst possible solution. Don't try this at home, kids. :)

Comment: @Emil, is that because it's PHP or uses strings? I'll give you the latter.

Comment: For using strings to do math. I still use PHP everyonce in a while myself, even though I've been trying harder and harder not to...

Comment: @Emil, fair. I actually tried the bitwise operators, but **stackunderflow** beat me to it. So I provided something else. Thanks for calling me out ;)